# Как сгруппировать ссылки по домену?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

Задача следующая: мне нужно получить все ссылки с сайта, сгруппировать их по доменам, и посчитать каждую из ссылок.

То есть, примерно так:

**www.google.com - 54 ссылок**

**www.youtube.com - 21 ссылок**

**www.yandex.ru - 34 ссылок**

Как это можно сделать? Сразу хочу сказать, что изучаю Python меньше недели, и пока не разобрался. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

**Код:**

```
import requests
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,features='html.parser')
links = soup.findAll("a", attrs={'href': re.compile("https://")})
for i in links:
    print(str(len(links)) + '   ' + str(i.get('href').split('/')[2]))
```

Comment: И есть ли в BS4 что-то для сортировки доменов? Простой sort не работает.

Answer (score 0):

После выполнения кода в `link_count_dict` хранится количество ссылок с одним доменом, в `link_dict` сгруппированные по домену ссылки.

```
import requests
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,features='html.parser')
links = soup.findAll("a", attrs={'href': re.compile("https://")})
for i in links:
    print(str(len(links)) + '   ' + str(i.get('href').split('/')[2]))


link_count_dict={}
link_dict={}
for link in links:
    dom = link.get('href').split('/')[2]
    link_dict[dom] = []
    if link_count_dict.get(dom):
        link_count_dict[dom]+=1
    else:
        link_count_dict[dom]=1

keys=link_dict.keys()
for key in keys:
    for link in links:
        if key in link.get('href'):
            link_dict[key].append(link.get('href'))
```